# Unable to get correct session factory

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am using hibernate along side spring to configure the session factory and hibernate transaction manager, below mentioned is the apllication-context file---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd">

    <beans profile="nondev,dev">

        <context:annotation-config />
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.woodmac" />

        <import resource="classpath:spring/applicationContext-soap.xml" />
        <import resource="classpath:spring/applicationContext-cache.xml" />
        <import resource="classpath:spring/applicationContext-mail.xml" />
        <import resource="classpath:spring/applicationContext-batchJobs.xml" />


        <bean name="ecommSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="ecommDataSource" />
            <property name="hibernateProperties" ref="hibernateProperties" />
            <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.woodmac" />
        </bean>

        <bean name="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="hibernateProperties" ref="hibernateProperties" />
            <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.woodmac" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="hibernateProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
            <property name="properties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">${hibernate.use_sql_comments}</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_statement</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <!-- 
            Source: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC3/reference/html/ch12s03.html

            A DataSource is part of the JDBC specification and is a generalized connection factory. It allows a container or a 
            framework to hide connection pooling and transaction management issues from the application code. 

            NOTE: DriverManagerDataSource 
            class is not an actual connection pool; it does not actually pool Connections. It just serves as simple replacement for a 
            full-blown connection pool, implementing the same standard interface, but creating new Connections on every call. -->
        <!-- 
        <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
            <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}" />
            <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
            <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />

            <property name="minPoolSize" value="${hibernate.c3p0.minPoolSize}" />
            <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${hibernate.c3p0.maxPoolSize}" />
            <property name="maxIdleTime" value="${hibernate.c3p0.idleTestPeriod}" />

            <property name="maxConnectionAge" value="${hibernate.c3p0.maxConnectionAge}" />
            <property name="maxStatements" value="${hibernate.c3p0.max_statement}" />

            <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="${hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout}" />
            <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="${hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery}" />
            <property name="debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces" value="${hibernate.c3p0.debug}" />
        </bean>
        -->

        <!-- This bean is the Spring Hibernate transaction manager that will handle transaction related boilerplate code and wiring 
            for us. We needed to define the session factory that the transaction manager will use to create sessions -->
        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"
            p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" depends-on="sessionFactory">
        </bean>

        <!-- This bean is the spring hibernate transaction manager for new session factory -->
        <bean id="ecommTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"
            p:sessionFactory-ref="ecommSessionFactory" depends-on="sessionFactory">
        </bean>


        <!-- Transaction Management tx:annotation-driven element defines that we are declaring transactions using annotations in 
            our classes. -->
        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true" />

        <!-- Transaction management for the ecommerce transactions  -->
        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="ecommTransactionManager" proxy-target-class="true" />

        <!-- the transactional advice (i.e. what 'happens'; see the <aop:advisor/> bean below) -->
        <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
            <!-- the transactional semantics... -->
            <tx:attributes>
                <!-- all methods starting with 'get', 'select', 'find' are read-only -->
                <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" propagation="SUPPORTS" />
                <tx:method name="select*" read-only="true" propagation="SUPPORTS" />
                <tx:method name="find*" read-only="true" propagation="SUPPORTS" />
                <tx:method name="fetch*" read-only="true" propagation="SUPPORTS" />
                <!-- other methods use the default transaction settings -->
                <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
            </tx:attributes>
        </tx:advice>
    </beans>

    <!-- Note: Only use the DriverManagerDataSource class should only be used for testing purposes since it does not provide 
        pooling and will perform poorly when multiple requests for a connection are made. -->
    <beans profile="dev-notinuse">
        <!-- <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
            p:url="${jdbc.url}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}">
        </bean>  -->
        <!-- <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
            <property name="jndiName" value="${portal.ds.jndi}"/>
        </bean> -->
    </beans>

    <beans profile="nondev, dev">
        <jee:jndi-lookup id="ecommDataSource" jndi-name="${ecommerce.ds.jndi}" lookup-on-startup="true" lazy-init="false" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
        <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="${portal.ds.jndi}" lookup-on-startup="true" lazy-init="false" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
    </beans>
</beans>
```

Now in the test DAO that I have written to call a stored procedure ---

```
package com.woodmac.component.event.dao.impl;

import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.jdbc.Work;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.woodmac.component.event.dao.IEventDAO;
import com.woodmac.generic.dao.impl.EcommDaoImpl;

/**
 * The Class EventDAOImpl.
 */
@Component
@Qualifier("eventDAO")
@Transactional
@DependsOn("ecommSessionFactory")
public class EventDAOImpl extends EcommDaoImpl implements IEventDAO{

    public Integer callSqlBlock(){

        Session session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        final Integer outputValue =1;
        session.doWork(new Work() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void execute(Connection conn)
                                                throws SQLException {
                                              CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("? = call test(?)");
                                              stmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.INTEGER);
                                              stmt.setString(2, "callIndex");
                                              stmt.execute();
                                              Integer output = stmt.getInt(1);
                                              System.out.println("outputValue is"+outputValue); 
                                           }
                        });
        return outputValue;
}
}
```

But unfortunately this is giving me a different session factory than expected that is the connection string I am getting is of the other schema henceforth I am getting a bad sql exception.

Where I am going wrong on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you're saying is that `getHibernateTemplate()` returns a template with the wrong session factory?  You're creating 2 session factories but not explicitly stating which one gets assigned to the EventDAOImpl instance.

@DependsOn only states that the object will be created by Spring *after* the ecommSessionFactory, that does not mean that it will be given that one.

[See here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html)

`Beans on which the current bean depends. Any beans specified are guaranteed to be created by the container before this bean. Used infrequently in cases where a bean does not explicitly depend on another through properties or constructor arguments, but rather depends on the side effects of another bean's initialization.
May be used on any class directly or indirectly annotated with Component or on methods annotated with Bean.`

I'd create the `EventDAOImpl` in my XML file and specify the SessionFactory bean that you want injected in the XML (either the ecommSessionFactory or the sessionFactory, I'm not sure which you want).  Something like this:

```
<bean name="eventDAO" class=".....EventDaoImpl">
            <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="whicheverOneItShouldBe" />
```

Comment: Is there's any programmatic way to do this rather than specifying in configuration as otherwise I will have to make multiple entries in configuration file, which I don't want